# Is it possible to display rotated DataGridView in Windows Form which add row dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following windows forms where I can add the DataGrid using the component list. The following is the DataGridView:

[image: input image]

I am adding the rows dynamically. There is no Data Source aligned. I am adding it by the command:

```
datagridview1.Rows.Add(value1, value2, ... valueN);
```

But the view I am getting is table sort of,, as you see in the image.

I want it to look like this:

[image: output image]

But I cannot get any option for this or even a method that will help me make this.

Can anybody please tell me what I can do to get this sort of component or look of the data grid view?

Comment: Can somebody please let me know what I can do in this situation?

Comment: Do you just want the date to be rotated or the characters? For the former you can change your code but for the latter I have my doubts, esp if you want it to work interactively.. (You would have to draw each cell yourself)

Comment: @TaW I did not understand what you want to say, as there are no dates if you see. There are only numbers. I just want to rotate the datagrid from horizontal to vertical. Please can you suggest me what to do. If not datagrid then what component will be helpful? Please guide me.

Comment: Numbers are data. Again: do you want the charcters/digts to be rotated? Why??? Or only exchange rows for columns? Users usually will not like their data to be tilted..

Comment: @TaW Yes I want to rotate the data as well, actually I just rotated the image of the grid. Can you tell me whether it can be done or not?

Comment: If not then what component can be used for this purpose? Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: @TaW I do not want to rotate as shown in the figure. I was not able to make an image that will show data straight. I do not want to the data to be rotated. Is this answering your question?

Comment: Okay now I tried to make the correct  image please check this.

Comment: @TaW Can you help me now?

Comment: OK, so you want rows and columns switched?  Since you are adding the rows yourself all you need is change the loops (?) a little, maybe adding the rows as `datagridview1.Rows.Add(col1valueN, col2valueN, ... colMvalueN);` etc.. Or fill them cell by cell. It is harder for databound DGVs which need rotated datasources..